# MS VBA - Running Macro w/o Changing File type

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a folder that contains the following files:

1. SRJem.xlsx
2. Master File.xltm
3. Service Report Printer.docx

The workbook *SRJem.xlsx* is a file in which all my inputs come in (normally I paste from manual inputs of our custodians here), which is then copied by a MS Word macro in *Service Report Printer.docx* to be printed immediately (because the form is so distorted, I had to code it this way). Also, the contents of *SRJem.xlsx* is then transferred as a report in the *Master File.xltm* (Note the filetype as Excel Macro-enabled Template).

The hard part is, I have to manually run the macro in the *Service Report Printer.docx* file and the *Master File.xltm* file.

I tried to code in *SRJem.xlsx* file, (saving this now as `xltm` file instead of `xlsx`) but the hard part is the *Master File* macro reopens the *SRJem.xltm* as *SRJem1.xltm* therefore disrupting my code in *Master File* needing me to save again.

**Is there a workaround to this?**

**If not by code, how should I think so that two code runs simultaneously from a single input file without altering the filename of the input file during reopening?** or

**Is there a way such that *Master File* does not reopen the source `xltm` file?**

Here is my code for the **Master File.xltm**

```
Sub transfer_to_masterfile()

'find first empty row in database
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("1")
Dim wbSource As Workbook

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx") ' <<< path to source workbook

Set sh = wbSource.Worksheets("1")

'Now, transfer values from wbSource to wbTarget:
'ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "*"
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = sh.Cells(14, 1).Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = sh.Cells(6, 4).Value

Dim mats As String
Dim row As Integer

row = 23
mats = ""

Do
    mats = mats & "  " & sh.Cells(row, 1).Value & "  " & sh.Cells(row, 3).Value & _
    "             " & sh.Cells(row, 5).Value

    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 1).Value > 0 Then
        mats = mats & vbNewLine
    End If

    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    row = row + 1

Loop Until row = 42

ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = mats

Dim hourswork As String
hourswork = ""
row = 46
Do
    hourswork = hourswork & sh.Cells(row, 5).Value & " hrs"
    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 5).Value <> "" Then
        hourswork = hourswork & vbNewLine
    End If
    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 5).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop Until row = 51
ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = hourswork

Dim rate As String
rate = ""
row = 46
Do
    rate = rate & sh.Cells(row, 15).Value
    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 15).Value <> "" Then
        rate = rate & vbNewLine
    End If
    If sh.Cells(row + 1, 15).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop Until row = 51
ws.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = rate

ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Format(sh.Cells(20, 5), "MMM. DD, YYYY")
ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Format(sh.Cells(20, 15), "MMM. DD, YYYY")
ws.Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Format(sh.Cells(43, 17), "###,###.00")
ws.Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Format(sh.Cells(52, 17), "###,###.00")

wbSource.Quit

Set wbSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

While, here is my code for the **Service Report Printer.docx**

```
Sub Clear_Document()
Dim oShp As Word.Shape
Dim i As Long

For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
    If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        oShp.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub ReadyForPrinting()

sPrompt = "Please enter sheet name: "
sTitle = "Sheet Reference"
sDefault = sSheetRef
sSheetRef = InputBox(sPrompt, sTitle, sDefault)

Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx")

Dim client As Shape
Set client = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=95, Top:=115, Width:=500, Height:=20)
client.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(6, 4)
client.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
client.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
client.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
With client.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim requestdate_word As Shape
Set requestdate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=420, Top:=127, Width:=500, Height:=20)
requestdate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(6, 15)
requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With requestdate_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim clientlocation As Shape
Set clientlocation = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=95, Top:=124, Width:=500, Height:=20)

clientlocation.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(7, 4)
clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With clientlocation.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim contactperson_word As Shape
Set contactperson_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=110, Top:=138, Width:=500, Height:=20)

contactperson_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(8, 4)
contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With contactperson_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim telno_word As Shape
Set telno_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=400, Top:=150, Width:=500, Height:=20)

telno_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(8, 15)
telno_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
telno_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
telno_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With telno_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim workdescription As Shape
Set workdescription = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=50, Top:=202, Width:=500, Height:=20)

workdescription.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(14, 1)
workdescription.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
workdescription.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
workdescription.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
With workdescription.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim inspectedby_word As Shape
Set inspectedby_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=80, Top:=243, Width:=500, Height:=20)

inspectedby_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(18, 1)
inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
With inspectedby_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim datestarted As Shape
Set datestarted = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=135, Top:=258, Width:=300, Height:=20)
datestarted.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(20, 5)
datestarted.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
datestarted.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
datestarted.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With datestarted.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim datefinished As Shape
Set datefinished = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=442, Top:=270, Width:=300, Height:=20)
datefinished.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(20, 15)
datefinished.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
datefinished.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
datefinished.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With datefinished.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim inspecteddate_word As Shape
Set inspecteddate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=236, Top:=250, Width:=500, Height:=20)
inspecteddate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(18, 8)
inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
With inspecteddate_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim confirmedby_word As Shape
Set confirmedby_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=373, Top:=252, Width:=500, Height:=20)

confirmedby_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(18, 11)
confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With confirmedby_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim confirmeddate_word As Shape
Set confirmeddate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=510, Top:=255, Width:=500, Height:=20)
confirmeddate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(18, 17)
confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With confirmeddate_word.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

'merge nalang ang items. :)

Dim materials As Shape
Set materials = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=44, Top:=300, Width:=500, Height:=300)

Dim mats As String
Dim mats2 As String
Dim r As Integer
mats = ""
r = 24

Do
    mats = mats & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 1) & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 3) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 5) & vbNewLine
    r = r + 1
Loop Until r = 42

materials.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = mats

materials.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
materials.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
materials.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2.4
With materials.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim materials2 As Shape
Set materials2 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=440, Top:=314, Width:=400, Height:=400)

r = 24

Do
    mats2 = mats2 & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 15) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 17) & vbNewLine
    r = r + 1
Loop Until r = 42

materials2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = mats2

materials2.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
materials2.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
materials2.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2.5
With materials2.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim mattotal As Shape
Set mattotal = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=520, Top:=515, Width:=300, Height:=20)

mattotal.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(43, 17)
mattotal.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
mattotal.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
mattotal.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

With mattotal.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

'merge labor number of days rate
Dim labor As Shape
Dim lab As String
Set labor = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=44, Top:=545, Width:=800, Height:=500)

r = 46

Do
    lab = lab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 1) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 5) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 15) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(r, 17) & vbNewLine
    r = r + 1
Loop Until r = 51

labor.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = lab
labor.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
labor.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
labor.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1.5
With labor.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim labtotal As Shape
Set labtotal = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=525, Top:=625, Width:=300, Height:=20)

labtotal.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(52, 17)
labtotal.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
labtotal.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
labtotal.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

With labtotal.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim totalcost As Shape
Set totalcost = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=525, Top:=640, Width:=300, Height:=20)

totalcost.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(53, 17)
totalcost.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
totalcost.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
totalcost.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

With totalcost.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim preparedby As Shape
Set preparedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=225, Top:=680, Width:=300, Height:=20)
preparedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(57, 7)
preparedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
preparedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
preparedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
With preparedby.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim checkedby As Shape
Set checkedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=355, Top:=680, Width:=300, Height:=20)
checkedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(57, 12)
checkedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
checkedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
checkedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1
With checkedby.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

Dim approvedby As Shape
Set approvedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=480, Top:=683, Width:=300, Height:=20)
approvedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets(sSheetRef).Cells(57, 16)
approvedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
approvedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
approvedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1

With approvedby.Line
    .Visible = msoFalse
End With

objExcel.Quit

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

I know, I know, my code is nasty but this is all I have for now. Sorry. :)

Comment: You could consider transferring the code from your xltm file into your personal macro file or as an add-in, using an xlam file.  I prefer using add-ins as they can be used by others and they do not require xlsm files to be transferred around which require others to enable macros and are often discouraged by email servers.

Comment: I will try this on Monday when I get to the office and give you feedbacks, Sir. Thank you.

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your comment. But my problem is that, xlam files are supposed not to have inputs as it is an add-in. In the question above, my XLTM file is supposed to extract data from XLSX file. Am I in correct thinking? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you are correct, you simply store all of the code in your .xlam addin (meaning you don't need code in the other workbooks) and use the other workbooks for the in/output

Comment: @Wolfie, Oh i see! Will this mean that all my other workbooks will now have the macro, and can be saved as XLSX? Thank you.

Comment: Correct, and the code can be included in any future workbooks without needing to add it manually. Ensure you share the addin with the workbook if you want the macro functionality to exist when moving the file!

Comment: This is amazing. I never thought Excel can do this! This will really help me. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Wolfie, can you put that as your answer so that I can accept? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all of your code in a .xlam Excel addin.

This means you wouldn't need any code in the other workbooks, just use them for input/output.
Here is a detailed [MSDN technical article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx) with all the details about creating your own addins. If that article is a little heavy, there are many [other resources](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/06/16/excel-toolbox-save-your-custom-functions-and-macros-in-an-add-in/) online to guide you.

The macros of an addin workbook can be accessed by your other workbooks if you make sure to load the addin. Please see [this Microsoft support link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-add-ins-in-Excel-0af570c4-5cf3-4fa9-9b88-403625a0b460) for details about doing so.

One thing to consider is making the xlam file read only (right click on the file, Properties, check Read Only). This is especially important if you are sharing the xlam file on a network. If anyone opens Excel and loads the addin, you will not be able to edit it until Excel is fully closed on their machines. This can be problematic in an office environment.

For ease, the addin should be in your addins directory, or the same directory as the workbook(s) which use it.